# instagram (new rules) follow/unfollow possible via API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I have an instagram account.

I want to achieve 2 things..

1. I want to be able to unfollow all users that I am following.
2. I want to be able to follow users that are following a specific user.

As i've read through, i couldn't find enough information if this can be done...

Any documentation or strict word if it can not be done or if it can ?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using unofficial api, check [this](https://github.com/dilame/instagram-private-api), but make sure you do it only for educational purpose. And don't try it too hard, or instagram will block you.